# PHP when output something before header or session_start without ob_start

Tags: php

I have been told when output something like echo/var_dump before header() or session_start, a warning will be shown like this "php Cannot send session cookie-headers already sent by".

But the following code works fine. It is strange! Who can tell me the reason? PHP version is 5.6.9

```
<?php 
echo 'hello';
setcookie('a','a');
session_start();
$_SESSION['a'] = 'a';
header("location:test.php");
?>
```

Comment: Most likely it's because of [output_buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.examples.basic.php) as [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php?rq=1) (It's a bit down in the answer - _Bring a shovel cause you'll need to dig_).

Comment: You said 'following code'. Where is it?

Comment: @Epodax A bit down? More like buried :-)

Comment: On web or on local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use output_buffering = On in your php.ini you can send cookies after the headers have been sent.

As stated in php.ini comment :

> Output buffering allows you to send header lines (including cookies)
>   even after you send body content, at the price of slowing PHP's output
>   layer a bit. You can enable output buffering during runtime by calling
>   the output buffering functions. You can also enable output buffering
>   for all files by setting this directive to On. If you wish to limit
>   the size of the buffer to a certain size - you can use a maximum
>   number of bytes instead of 'On', as a value for this directive (e.g.,
>   output_buffering=4096).